# How to align some text as center and some text as align right within a single cell in a table

Tags: xsl-fo

How to align some text as center and some text as right align in the same line within a single cell within a table In XSL-FO only.

Comment: Can you add a graphic or ASCII Art rendition of what you want?  I have provided two answers, and each answer has prompted new details about what you want. @Ifurini has also suggested that a more precise description would help.  We're trying to help, but we don't have enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Put each block of text in a separate `fo:block`. Use `text-align="center"` on the first `fo:block`, and use `text-align="right"` on the second.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#text-align.

Comment: If i use two separate fo:block then that text will come in new line. I want in the same line please help me

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please see my other answer.  It might have saved me from myself if you had shown some sample XML and maybe a faked output, but that doesn't excuse my misreading.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fo:leader` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_leader).

Using just `<fo:leader />` when there is `text-align="justify"` on the `fo:block` may be sufficient.

If that doesn't give the right result, it may be because the default .optimum value for the `leader-length` property (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#leader-length) is 12pt.  In that case, you probably want something like:

```
<fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%" />
```

If you are using AH Formatter, you can use `axf:leader-expansion="force"` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.leader-expansion) to force the leader to expand as much as possible.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how this would work: using a single `fo:leader` would allow to achieve left-aligned and right-aligned text on the same line, but that is not the desired output; having `fo:leader` + text1 + `fo:leader` + text2 would put text1 in the middle _between the left margin and the beginning of text2_, not in the center between the margins.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you really need to have both the centered text and the right-aligned text inside the same `fo:table-cell`, you could use a **negative space** between two `fo:block` elements to put them apparently on the same line:

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block text-align="center" space-after="-14.4pt">in the center</fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="right">to the right</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

This should work (I tested it with FOP), but it may be considered a bit of a dirty trick; the exact value for `space-after` depends on the line height for the first block, which defaults to 1.2 * font-size (itself defaulting to 12pt), so you may have to compute the correct value for your specific situation.

*However*, I think in many situations you could just

1. use a 3-column table with the first and the third one having equal width
2. put the centered text in the second cell
3. put the right-aligned text in the third cell
4. define a border only outside the table row, so the three cells appear as a single one in the output.

(as Tony Graham already commented, a more precise description of the desired output, or even better an image showing it, would help suggesting the right answer for your situation)